# How to make the height jQuery tabs content 800 px?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-tabs

I'm using [this jquery ui tabs plugin](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/),the content of each tab is an `<iframe>`:

```
<p><iframe src="xxx.php" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"></iframe></p>
```

However the height of the tab content is about `400px`,how can I make it `800px` so that the scroll bar of `<iframe>` can disappear?

Answer (score 2):

Is there a reason you couldn't specify that the height of the iframe is 800px?  i.e.

```
<p><iframe src="xxx.php" style="width: 100%; height: 800px;"></iframe></p>
```